# Program is not displaying any output

Tags: python, output, whoosh

```
import os, os.path
from whoosh.index import create_in
from whoosh.fields import *
schema = Schema(title=TEXT(stored=True), path=ID(stored=True), content=TEXT)

if not os.path.exists("indexdir"):
    os.mkdir("indexdir")


ix = create_in("indexdir", schema)
writer = ix.writer()
writer.add_document(title=u"First document", path=u"/a",
                 content=u"This is the first document we've added!")
writer.add_document(title=u"Second document", path=u"/b",
                 content=u"The second one is even more interesting!")
writer.commit()
from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser

with ix.searcher() as searcher:
    query = QueryParser("content", ix.schema).parse("first")
    results = searcher.search(query)
    results[0]
```

It looks okay, but it is not displaying any results.

Comment: Well you don't have any print statements in it. What did you expect it to display?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want you last line to be:

`print results[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Python requires you to explicitly print output by using [`print`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement):

```
print results[0]
```

Note however that the above code is for Python 2.x.  In Python 3.x, `print` was converted into a [function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

```
print(results[0])
```